# Regex validating string of numbers

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am trying create regex witch will start with some number like 230, 420, 7456. Then could be some number in interval 1-9 but the final length must be 9.

For example `230888333` or `745623777`

I create this:

`([(230|420|7456)[0-9]{1,}]{9})`

But it is not correct. Any idea how to make this correct?

Thaks.

Comment: Assert the number of digits `^(?=[0-9]{9}$)(?:230|420|7456)[0-9]+$`

Comment: If you use Javascript, the solution of Code Maniac might be the more intuitive one.

Comment: `^((230|420)[0-9]{6})|(7456[0-9]{5})$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you tried is not anchored, and the current notation uses a character class `[...]` instead of a grouping (the `]{9}` part at the end repeats 9 times a `]` char)

---

If you use C# then use `[0-9]` to match a digit 0-9.

You can either assert 9 digits in total:

```
^(?=[0-9]{9}$)(?:230|420|7456)[0-9]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ur1kl/1)

Or write an alternation for different leading lengths of digits:

```
^(?:(?:230|420)[0-9]{6}|7456[0-9]{5})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rzMfJ6/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a check for length first and then simple regex

```js
function checkString(str){
  return str.length === 9 && /^(?:230|420|7456)\d+$/.test(str)
}

console.log(checkString("230888333"))
console.log(checkString("745623777"))
console.log(checkString("123"))
console.log(checkString("230888333123"))
```